# Dual of path object

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

For a topological space $X$, what might be the dual of the path space $X^I$ of $X$? Does it make any sense to think of the topological cylinder $X \times I$ over $X$ as dual to the path space over $X$?

Comment: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponential+object

Comment: Yes, do you know what's a path object in model categories? See page 810 in http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/highertopoi.pdf . Furthermore, exponential is adjoint to taking the product.

Comment: @user40276 That's what I was looking for, thanks!